# Trying to get property of non-object in codeigniter user login

Tags: php, codeigniter

below is the code of  for login user (this is a model one) i cannot find out the problem can some one tell me ? i have use codeigniter database for session that ci_session

```
public function login() {
    $user = array (

            'email' => $this->input->post ( 'email' ),
            'password' => $this->input->post ( 'password' ),

            TRUE
    );

    if (count ( $user )) {

        $data = array (

                'email' => $user->name,
                'name' => $user->name,
                'password' => $user->passsword,
                'id' => $user->id,
                'loggedin' => TRUE
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata ( $data );
    }
}
```

Comment: this is my var_dump

array
  'session_id' => string '411d77551192576abab369e16d8c9eb5' (length=32)
  'ip_address' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
  'user_agent' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0' (length=72)
  'last_activity' => int 1415022883
  'user_data' => string '' (length=0)
  'email' => null
  'name' => null
  'password' => null
  'id' => null
  'loggedin' => boolean true

Comment: you missed `name` field at your `$user` array, you cannot get access array element like this $user->name use `$user['name']` thats why it produce that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$user is currently defined as an array and you are looking for an object within your $data array.  You also haven't defined name, id, and you have a typo in `passsword.`

You could change your $data array to look like this to fix the errors.

```
$data = array (

            'email' => $user['email'],
            'name' => $user['email'],
            'password' => $user['password'],
            'loggedin' => TRUE
    );
```

Comment: undefined index password and user name , :/

Comment: its not receiving the id and name

Comment: Yeah, it looks to me what you'd want to do is get the user record from the database after verifying the email/password then store that information in the session.  That way you'd have the ID and name of the user.